What aircraft used this compass?
I was wondering if anyone had any info on this compass I have.



It's a magnetic compass ordered by the USAF. I don't think there is any way to figure out exactly what aircraft this specific compass was installed in. It is way too generic of a part to determine that.

Corresponding specifications, confirming a general use (§6.1).

This model compass was used on many USAF aircraft, B2, B52, F4, F18,C17, C130, and SH60 and HH60 helicopters.
Judging by the relatively low SN, I would guess B52, C130, or F4.
